# How to abbreviate "verrouillée"?

Tags: traduction, abréviations

I need to write "Porte verrouillée" ("Door Locked") to a computer display, but I only have 14 characters. How can I abbreviate "verrouillée" to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: You could try to impress your clients with your knowledge of Existentialism and/or the French judicial system with [**“Huis clos”**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/huis)!

Comment: fermé à clé=FAC

Comment: On French keyboards, "Num lock" is "Verr. num." for "verrouillage numérique". So "porte verr." sounds totally right to me.

Answer (score 5):

*Verrouillé*, while comprehensible, is not the most common way of saying that a door is locked. *Fermé à clé* is more common. Depending on the context, ***porte fermée*** may be an adequate translation. Since it could mean either shut or locked, this is only suitable if there's no reason why the display would indicate that the door is shut.

Conversely, if it's clear that the display is about a door, then ***verrou fermé*** would work. While it isn't an idiomatic way of saying that a door is locked, it's absolutely comprehensible. *Verrou enclenché* (“lock engaged”) is more idiomatic but doesn't fit, however ***verrou enclenc*** or ***verrou encl*** or ***verr enclenché*** might be acceptable. None of these abbreviations are immediately clear, but they're guessable.

For an electronic lock, ***verrou activé*** is another possibility. It doesn't really work for a mechanical lock.

Otherwise ***porte verr.*** or ***porte verrouil*** are decent ways of abbreviating *porte verrouillée*.

If the accent on the *e* can't be shown then it's best to avoid the word *fermé* because *ferme* also exists and means something completely different. *Fermée* misspelled as **fermee* is less bad because that spelling doesn't exist so *fermée* is a natural correction. In this case ***serrure fermee*** might be a better alternative to **verrou ferme*.

How acceptable these are depends on where the display is (is it next to the door and unambiguously related to it or remote?) and who will see it (do random people need to understand it in an emergency or is this only for trained personnel?). I don't think there's a one-14-character-size-fits-all solution in French.

Comment: Saying that a "serrure" is "fermée" seems incorrect to me. "Porte fermée" is definitely what's best

Comment: @ValentinBerthelot “Verrou fermé” is correct, “serrure fermée” isn't, but in everyday usage people don't really distinguish between *verrou* and *serrure*.

Comment: Good post ! Not sure why *"serrure fermée"* is incorrect. :x

Answer (score 2):

Concernant "verrouillée", l'abréviation utilisée sur les claviers d'ordinateurs est "Verr." (Comme dans "Verr. Maj." ("Caps Lock")).[verr maj](https://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infobidouille.com%2Fvx%2Farticles%2F25%2Fverr-maj.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infobidouille.com%2Farticles%2F25%2F2-presentation-test-clavier-logitech-dinovo-notebook&docid=cNhxoVss4Zy6yM&tbnid=Iw7_tzjew-4miM%3A&w=1600&h=806&hl=en-ca&safe=off&client=safari&bih=628&biw=414&ved=0ahUKEwjIjvHNv_PPAhXFwj4KHa3TCbUQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comme alternative, je propose "Porte barrée" qui est commun, du moins au Quebec.

Comment: En France, je comprends « porte barrée » comme une porte qui est infranchissable en permanence (ou à la rigueur qui déclenche une alarme). C'est différent au Québec ?

Comment: Oui ça l'est. La signification dont vous parlez est secondaire plutôt que primaire au Quebec dans mon expérience.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur L'expression "une porte barrée" ou "barrer la porte" (pour "verrouiller") est un régionalisme en France ; l'expression est commune dans le Poitou mais je ne l'ai jamais entendue ailleurs.

Comment: La France n'est pas la francophonie.

Answer (score 1):

serrure fermée

verrou tiré

porte bouclée

porte bloquée (sens un peu différent)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any natural and understandable way to abbreviate "verrouillée" so I would rather suggest to write:

> Porte fermée

Comment: "verr" as is "verr num" on the keyboard ?